# State is undefined when passing it to a child component

Tags: reactjs, components, state

Hello all you fellow coders out there. I'm fairly new to react and I'm wondering what is the best way to handle a situation as follows:

My root component has a form which defines at submit which list of objects it should pass to the child component to map and render. However after the objects are set as a state of the root component and passed to the child component as it renders it will be unable to map as the state isn't yet updated and is undefined because of this.

So anyway what is the right way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue via an if statement which returns null if the list of objects isn't set. Is this the right way to go about it though?

Comment: Yup, `if statement` good idea. Also, you can add loader to child component or alert notification, when props empty yet.